# SBT dependency resolution is too slow with messages : dependency descriptor has been mediated

Tags: sbt, ivy, jfrog-cli, aws-codeartifact, coursier

I am trying to migrate my scala-sbt project artifactory from JFrog to AWS Codeartifact. I am able to resolve dependencies, compile and publish the jars back to AWS Codeartifact with only one problem, the compilation is too slow.

I see that with AWS Codeartifact, SBT is not using coursier even when I explicitly ask it to use with these options `-Dsbt.ivy=false -Dsbt.coursier=true`. I see all the dependencies getting downloaded in to `~/.ivy2/` location.

Also I see a lot of messages like this

```
 dependency descriptor has been mediated: dependency: io.netty#netty-buffer;4.1.75.Final {compile=[compile(*), master(compile)], runtime=[runtime(*)]} => dependency: io.netty#netty-buffer;4.1.77.Final {compile=[compile(*), master(compile)], runtime=[runtime(*)]}
[debug] dependency descriptor has been mediated: dependency: io.netty#netty-codec-http;4.1.75.Final {compile=[compile(*), master(compile)], runtime=[runtime(*)]} => dependency: io.netty#netty-codec-http;4.1.77.Final {compile=[compile(*), master(compile)], runtime=[runtime(*)]}
[debug] == resolving dependencies com.concentra#http4d_2.13;2.0.1->org.http4s#http4s-async-http-client_2.13;0.23.11 [compile->compile(*)]
[debug] dependency descriptor has been mediated: dependency: io.netty#netty-buffer;4.1.75.Final {compile=[compile(*), master(compile)], runtime=[runtime(*)]} => dependency: io.netty#netty-buffer;4.1.77.Final {compile=[compile(*), master(compile)], runtime=[runtime(*)]}
[debug] dependency descriptor has been mediated: dependency: io.netty#netty-codec-http;4.1.75.Final {compile=[compile(*), master(compile)], runtime=[runtime(*)]} => dependency: io.netty#netty-codec-http;4.1.77.Final {compile=[compile(*), master(compile)], runtime=[runtime(*)]}
[debug] == resolving dependencies org.http4s#http4s-async-http-client_2.13;0.23.11->org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.13.8 [compile->master(compile)]
[debug] dependency descriptor has been mediated: dependency: io.netty#netty-buffer;4.1.75.Final {compile=[compile(*), master(compile)], runtime=[runtime(*)]} => dependency: io.netty#netty-buffer;4.1.77.Final {compile=[compile(*), master(compile)], runtime=[runtime(*)]}
[debug] dependency descriptor has been mediated: dependency: io.netty#netty-codec-http;4.1.75.Final {compile=[compile(*), master(compile)], runtime=[runtime(*)]} => dependency: io.netty#netty-codec-http;4.1.77.Final {compile=[compile(*), master(compile)], runtime=[runtime(*)]}
[debug] dependency descriptor has been mediated: dependency: io.netty#netty-buffer;4.1.75.Final {compile=[compile(*), master(compile)], runtime=[runtime(*)]} => dependency: io.netty#netty-buffer;4.1.77.Final {compile=[compile(*), master(compile)], runtime=[runtime(*)]}
[debug] dependency descriptor has been mediated: dependency: io.netty#netty-codec-http;4.1.75.Final {compile=[compile(*), master(compile)], runtime=[runtime(*)]} => dependency: io.netty#netty-codec-http;4.1.77.Final {compile=[compile(*), master(compile)], runtime=[runtime(*)]}
[debug] dependency descriptor has been mediated: dependency: io.netty#netty-buffer;4.1.75.Final {compile=[compile(*), master(compile)], runtime=[runtime(*)]} => dependency: io.netty#netty-buffer;4.1.77.Final {compile=[compile(*), master(compile)], runtime=[runtime(*)]}
[debug] dependency descriptor has been mediated: dependency: io.netty#netty-codec-http;4.1.75.Final {compile=[compile(*), master(compile)], runtime=[runtime(*)]} => dependency: io.netty#netty-codec-http;4.1.77.Final {compile=[compile(*), master(compile)], runtime=[runtime(*)]}
[debug] dependency descriptor has been mediated: dependency: io.netty#netty-buffer;4.1.75.Final {compile=[compile(*), master(compile)], runtime=[runtime(*)]} => dependency: io.netty#netty-buffer;4.1.77.Final {compile=[compile(*), master(compile)], runtime=[runtime(*)]}
[debug] dependency descriptor has been mediated: dependency: io.netty#netty-codec-http;4.1.75.Final {compile=[compile(*), master(compile)], runtime=[runtime(*)]} => dependency: io.netty#netty-codec-http;4.1.77.Final {compile=[compile(*), master(compile)], runtime=[runtime(*)]}
[debug] == resolving dependencies org.http4s#http4s-a
```

I am not sure what is the meaning of this message and I dont see this when I use JFrog artifactory and most of the messages are on `io.netty` dependency.

Has anyone faced similar issues? Is there a way to get rid of the descriptor has been mediated messages and speedup the resolution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though these `-Dsbt.ivy=false -Dsbt.coursier=true` did not take effect, when coursier was forced through project settings and plugin settings, I see significant improvement in resolution speed.

Project settings:

```
lazy val commonSettings = Seq(
    useCoursier := true, <<-- This change
    ------
```

Plugin settings in plugins.sbt

```
addSbtPlugin("org.scala-sbt"                     % "sbt-maven-resolver"  % "0.1.0")
    addDependencyTreePlugin
    useCoursier := true <<- This change
```

It also downloaded all the dependencies to the coursier path - `~/Library/Caches/Coursier/v1/https` instead of ivy path - `~/.ivy2/`. The overall dependency resolution + compilation speed is now on par with that of JFrog